# Why is scanf not working properly in codeblocks IDE

Tags: scanf, codeblocks

I am trying to run this code. This runs as expected up to printf statement but in the next line it doesn't. It shows the following message:-

Process returned 32767 (0x7FFF)   execution time : 3.404 s

Press any key to continue.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

```
int a, b;

printf("Enter two integers: ");

scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

return 0;
```

}

What am I doing wrong here? Why is scanf not working properly?

Comment: Disable your antivirus